# Amchart implemented from mysql data

Tags: amcharts

How can i implement mysql data into amchart?

amchart is a javascript, the code is as follow:

```
  var chartData = [{ country: "USA", visits: 4252 },
                    { country: "China", visits: 1882 },
                    { country: "Japan", visits: 1809 },
                    { country: "Germany", visits: 1322 },
                    { country: "UK", visits: 1122 },
                    { country: "France", visits: 1114 },
                    { country: "India", visits: 984 },
                    { country: "Spain", visits: 711 },
                    { country: "Netherlands", visits: 665 },
                    { country: "Russia", visits: 580 },
                    { country: "South Korea", visits: 443 },
                    { country: "Canada", visits: 441 },
                    { country: "Brazil", visits: 395 },
                    { country: "Italy", visits: 386 },
                    { country: "Australia", visits: 384 },
                    { country: "Taiwan", visits: 338 },
                    { country: "Poland", visits: 328}];
```

i would like to insert data into chartData in order to display the chart successfully.

Comment: What do you have tried?

Comment: We need more information. What exactly do you need help with? Do you need help with querying your database? Are you generating the page with amCharts or just the data? What's the backend language/framework? What's the mysql table and what not look like? Which version of amCharts?

Answer (score 2):

You can query the database and manipulate php array in the server side. then use following method to convert php array to json array in the server side.

```
json_encode(your php array);
```

Then pass this to client side(browser). If you do not know how to process mysql data to php array please ask.

Answer (score 2):

if you use version 4

```
chart.dataSource.url = "path/to/yourdata.php";
chart.dataSource.parser = new am4core.JSONParser();
chart.dataSource.parser.options.emptyAs = 0;
```

if you use version 3

```
"dataLoader": {
    "url": "path/to/yourdata.php"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

From your controller you can just simply return mysql data in array like
data_array = your mysql data that returns from query
and send this array with json and use this to your javascript function from where you requested amcharts

and in your javascript function use below code -

```
function create_chart(data_array){

$.each(data_array, function(key, value) {
  dataSet = {
    country: value1,
    visits: value2
   };
  chartData.push(dataSet);
});

chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.titleField = "country";
chart.valueField = "visits";
chart.write("chartdiv");
}
```

Comment: This answer makes a few presumptions, e.g. that the user has jQuery and is using amCharts v3 (v4 was recently released).